# Mysql, open connection if not opened, close if opened

Tags: python, mysql

How can i check if mysql is opened or closed?
Thanks

```
class MyConnection:

    def openDb(self):
      if not self.db:  
               self.db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root"
                        ,passwd="root",db="BloombergFinance")
    def closeDb(self):
        if self.db:
            self.db.close()

    def addListTicker(self,insertList):
        try:
           cur = self.db.cursor()
           cur.execute('insert into T...')  
           self.db.commit()
        finally:
            cur.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    mydb=MyConnection()     
    mydb.openDb() 
    mydb.addListTicker(...)
    mydb.closeDb()
```

This code gives error at the first time called, because python see self.db the first time.

```
AttributeError: MyConnection instance has no attribute 'db'
```

Comment: What do you call, that gives the error? Could you post a traceback?

Comment: And: if you don't define the `db` attribute for `MyConnection` class / instance, you'll get `AttributeError` when accessed. You may wish to set it to `None` at `__init__` or somewhere.

Comment: I edited question. Setting `none` at `__init__` will work i think. Let me try. Thanks